# Telnet on Windows 7 doesn’t connect to any server

Tags: windows-7, webserver, telnet

When I try to connect to a server with Telnet on Windows 7 x64, for example to Google:

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client
Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'
Microsoft Telnet> o www.google.com 80
Connecting To www.google.com...
```

After this, the frame of the window freezes for a minute or two and then:

```
Connecting To www.google.com...Could not open connection to the host,
on port 23: Connect failed
Microsoft Telnet>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the server for www.google.com is not allowing connection on port 23. 

Try to do `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`

Comment: Are you sure that it freezes? For me it looks like nothing happens until I start typing.

Comment: Just run `telnet www.google.com 80`

Comment: didnt work: Microsoft Telnet> smtp.gmail.com 465
Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25
: Connect failed

Comment: You probably have a firewall in the way. Some of the anti-virus products include network interception that may block or terminate connections to certain ports. One I once had would trap any attempt to connect to port 25 and diverted it to a proxying component. Check you don't have such a system installed.

Answer (score 0):

**Shorter answer:** Are you sure it’s hanging? Because this doesn’t seem to be a Windows specific issue. Are you expecting a response header? Because I can get a `220` response header when I Telnet to port 25 on `smtp.gmail.com`.

**Longer answer:** To me, none of the responses seem abnormal; I do not see these outputs as “hanging.” But rather normal/expected behavior when operating at a raw, building-block level of a network.

For example when I attempt to Telnet to Google.com on port 80 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) it simply appears to “hang” as well:

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

The response I get is the following:

```
Trying 216.58.219.196...
Connected to www.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Ditto with attempting to connect to port `465` on Google’s SMTP server as suggested by a commenter:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
```

The response I get is the following:

```
Trying 74.125.141.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

But if I attempt to Telnet to port 25 I do get a server response:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
```

And here is what I get:

```
Trying 74.125.141.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP jk10sm23672404vdb.13 - gsmtp
```

Note the last line with the `220` response banner. I believe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Port 80 is HTTP, a protocol where the client speaks first; the server doesn't send anything until after you send it a request, or it times out which on my test is 4 minutes for google. As long as you don't make typing mistakes, `GET / HTTP/1.0` followed by *two* returns (sent as CRLF CRLF) is a minimal valid request. Port 465 is SMTP-over-SSL/TLS. SSL/TLS is also a client-first protocol, but it uses complicated binary formats that no human could enter from a keyboard or read from a screen.

Comment: I dont get any response like you got: Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.